# Show textareas values in parent component as a list & not showing tabs on page load

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, tabs, ngfor

I created a form with Angular Material, inside the form I have a mat-radio-group for radio buttons, and mat-tab-group
For tabs, each one of this tabs have an input. I have two questions.

1 - The tab group doesn’t show when the page loads, I have to click in a radio button to see the tabs, I don’t know why this is happening.

2 -  I am getting the values from the textareas and I am showing them in the parent component, When I write a new value in the text area, this one replace the previous value, but I need all the values from the different textareas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1st issue - not able to see tabs on reload/load

actually, as per the code, we are getting console errors, and because of that, we are not able to see tabs. it is breaking at the radio group itself.

### console errors

[image: console errors pic]

> Fix for the above issue - remove the `formControlName="titleAction"` for each radio button.

### 2nd issue - not getting all tabs data in a parent from child comp

so... here you are not sending all tabs data. that is the actual issue.
I did a few changes in child and parent as per your expected result.
sending array from child like below

```js
submit() {
    this.updateDataEvent.emit({formdata:this.form.getRawValue(), tabs: this.tabs});  
  }
```

and changed code in the parent component while updating a few global variables

```js
  updateData(selection: any): void {
    this.titleScreening =
      selection.formdata.titleAction === 'change'
        ? selection.formdata.titleText
        : 'Original Title';
    //Empty Inputs
    if (this.titleScreening === '') {
      this.titleScreening = 'Original Title';
    }
    this.divTag = this.divTag2 = ''
    selection.tabs.forEach((x) => {
      // this.name = x.fullName;
      var appendElement = '<li> <span> Name </span>' + x.name + '</li>';
      this.divTag = this.divTag + appendElement;

      // Show in parent component
      var appendElement2 = '<li> Value: ' + x.value + '</li>';
      this.divTag2 = this.divTag2 + appendElement2;
    });

    // selection.fullName === ''
    //   ? (this.divTag = '')
    //   : (this.divTag = appendElement);
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-components-demo-wqoqdz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Oh thanks, great solution! Did you change something in the child.component.ts related to how to get the tabs values? I can see the result of what you did but I can't access to the code.

Comment: @Bel now check the stackblitz example